# Spring framework monitoring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor queue size

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-jmx, jmxtrans

I checked http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html

There is no getter for queue size, only queue capacity.

If I use jmx to monnitor ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, how can I monitor queue size level to make sure it is healthy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size()`

**EDIT**

```
@ManagedResource
public class MyTEMBean {

    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor te;

    public MyTEMBean(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor te) {
        this.te = te;
    }

    @ManagedAttribute
    public int getQueueSize() {
        return this.te.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size();
    }

}
```

Comment: In this case, if I want to simply use jmxtrans-agent https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans-agent to query application, should I have my own executor extend this class and add getter for queue size. Does this sounds the right way?

Comment: Or a simple MBean wrapper exposing the properties you want - it doesn't have to be a subclass.

Comment: forgive my lack of knowledge, I thought jmx need to have getter for the attributes to be expose. If ThreadPoolTaskExecutor don't have such getter, and if I don't subclass to implement it. How Jmx can query this attributes? Curious what does it means by MBean wrapper. Great thanks

Comment: Just wrap the TE in a class and expose __that__ as an MBean instead of the TE itself. See the edit to my answer.