# Monitor currently running process via spring batch process and notify if the throttle limit is reached

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a spring boot web application and I want to upload details from CSV files through a batch process. Files can be upload from any location and  I want to restrict the process 3 jobs at a time. if already in process of 3 files, we have to give that information to UI as, "Throttle limit is being reached. Try after some time". How Could I achieve this?
My current flow.xml is with master slave approach

```
    <!-- partitioner job -->
    <job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <!-- master step -->
            <step id="masterStep">
              <partition step="slave" partitioner="partitioner">
                    <handler grid-size="1" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
               </partition>
            </step>

    </job>

    <!-- each thread will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext
    values. -->
    <step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
            <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"  throttle-limit="3">
                <chunk reader="itemReader" processor="userItemProcessor" writer="itemWriter"
               commit-interval="10" />
                 <listeners>
                        <listener ref="stepJobListener" />
                  </listeners>
            </tasklet>
    </step>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `throttle-limit="3"` that you've set on the step is for the threads that will run your step. For your use case, you should be looking for a way to configure the `TaskExecutor` that is used by the `JobLauncher` to limit the number of concurrent jobs.

You can for example configure the `JobLauncher` with a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` on which you set the `queueCapacity` to 3. With this configuration, if you submit more than 3 jobs at a time, the 4th submitted job will fail and you can show the error in your UI.

For the monitoring part, you can inspect the executor's queue size as described in [Spring framework monitoring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor queue size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115747/spring-framework-monitoring-threadpooltaskexecutor-queue-size)